# Why this expression equals an exponential?

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, exponential-function

I am currently going through the stochastic differential equations and can't go through one step. I have

$\sigma\cdot f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

And then:

$f(t,x) = \begin{equation} e^{\sigma x +g(x)} \end{equation}$

Why does one evaluates to another?

Comment: No $f(t,x)$ is not equal to $e^{\sigma x+g(x)}$. It is equal to $e^{\sigma x+g(t)}$. Don't you know how to solve a first order linear ODE ?

Comment: I am familiar with ODE but haven't solved a lot , but I don't see how I can approach this one. Could you help me please?

Comment: There is only one variable $x$ involved in the derivative. $t$ is just like a parameter. So you have to solve the ODE $\sigma f(x)= \frac{df}{dx}$ $$\sigma x=\int\frac{df}{f}+\text{constant with respect to } x \text{ but with } t \text{ into it.}$$

Comment: Yes, I solved that. But I am not sure I get where $g(t)$ comes from? Should there be just the constant?

Comment: $t$ is a parameter involved in the constant with respect to $x$ . Thus this is a function of $t$ but not a function of $x$.